# Unattended login to Facebook using Facebook connect

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, authentication

If I want my Facebook connect site to access user information about a Facebook user, is it necessary for that user to be logged in?

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary for them to either be logged in to facebook or for you to provide the facebook connect login.

From the Facebook Connect FAQ:

> A user can begin interacting with your
>   application immediately. For
>   applications within Facebook, you
>   don't need to have a user authorize
>   your application as soon as the user
>   visits your canvas page. See Automatic
>   Authentication:
>   http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Automatic_Authentication.
>
> A user authorizes an application when
>   the application presents a login
>   screen where the user accepts the
>   application's terms of service and
>   lets the application access his or her
>   profile data and creates a more
>   permanent connection.
>
> You can find out more here:
>   http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Authorizing_Applications

Comment: thanks for responding- i've had a look at the documentation, but just didn't want to believe the worst.

Comment: this looks promising. you can request that the user grant your application extended permissions, among which is a very interesting looking permission to grant your application access when the user is offline- haven't coded anything up yet, but after i do i will update.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions
offline_access - This permission grants an application access to user data when the user is offline or doesn't have an active session.

Answer (score 0):

If while authenticating your application from user you requested the "offline_access" [Extended permission](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions) then you will have an OAuth access token that will never Expire and you can use it to fetch user information from Graph api.

usually If the application has not requested offline_access permission, the access token is time-bounded. Time-bounded access token also get invalidated when the user logs out of Facebook. If the application has obtained offline_access permission from the user, the access token does not have an expiry. However it gets invalidated whenever the user changes his/her password.

But remember facebook insist on user initiated actions.